# Preventing Incorrect Template Matching OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv

I am using template matching in a project to find all the locations of a `subimage` in larger images. I am using the `OpenCV` methods `templateMatch()` and `floodFill()` (in Java) to accomplish this, and it is working properly, but only for larger images that DO contain the `subimage`.

```
Imgproc.matchTemplate(image, subimage, result, Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF);
```

If the larger image doesn't contain it, I am returned a huge list of incorrect locations. I want all the locations (if the subimage exists in the larger image), but NONE if it doesn't. How should I go about doing this? And if template matching is not the correct way to do it, what way should I do it then?

Btw my code is structured like this [Java opencv template matching and floodfill behavior.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088449/java-opencv-template-matching-and-floodfill-behavior)

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is way you can try, I know the problem which you mentioned, anyway, I found a solution for this, which is you can do threshold operation on the result image, for example the template match when find any match in image of a `sumimage`, then the position will shows in white color, when it founds good match the color can be more white, so you can threshold the image extract the good found position, and after you can do find contours or some other operation to get the contour position. Hope it can help you!